Calculate minimum amount of bribes required to reach all specified stops in a graph
Consider the following problem:
There are N towns (numbered 1 to N) and N - 1 roads connecting them (where 1 <= N <= 10^5). Some of these roads are unidirectional, but may be traversed illegally in the opposite direction by paying a bribe (starting at $1). After traversing a road in the wrong direction, the bribe required for the next time traversing the same road in the wrong direction doubles.
A driver starts from town 1 and has to make K stops (where 1 <= K <= 10^6) in the order that these stops are given. Given these stops, and the description of the roads, calculate the minimum amount of money required for bribes, modulo 10^9 + 7.

How can I solve this problem within 1 second?
Help me with my code, because for 100,000 towns Codeforces says time limit exceeded. I think that this Dijkstra is efficient, but maybe there is other place where maybe its second or third power.
What can I improve in my code.
It's a Codeforces problem Bribe so brute force or other greedy I think are not a good idea.
Input

The first line contains N, the number of towns in Ruritania. The following N - 1 lines contain information regarding individual roads between towns. A road is represented by a tuple of integers (a,b,x), which are separated with a single whitespace character. The numbers a and b represent the cities connected by this particular road, and x is either 0 or 1: 0 means that the road is bidirectional, 1 means that only the a → b direction is legal. The next line contains K, the number of stops Borna has to make. The final line of input contains K positive integers s1, …, sK: the towns Borna has to visit.

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int towns = scanner.nextInt();
        Graph g = new Graph(towns);
        for (int i = 0; i < towns-1; i++) {
            scanner.nextLine();
            int a =scanner.nextInt();
            int b =scanner.nextInt();
            int birection =scanner.nextInt();
            if(birection==0){
                g.addEdge(a-1,b-1,0);
                g.addEdge(b-1,a-1,0);

            }else{
                g.addEdge(a-1,b-1,0);
                g.addEdge(b-1,a-1,1);
            }

        }
        scanner.nextLine();
        int stops = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        int[] cities = new int[stops];
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            cities[i] = scanner.nextInt()-1;
        }
        scanner.close();
       //( g.print();
       /* for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(cities[i]+" ");

        }*/int stop=0;
        int j=0;
       //g.dfs(0,-1,2);
       // g.modDijkstra(3,4);
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            int endCity = cities[i];
            g.modDijkstra(j, endCity);
          //  System.out.println("Miasto 1 i 2: " + j + " " + endCity);
            j = endCity;
           // System.out.println(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(g.bribe);

    }

}


class Graph {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Para>> aL;
    boolean[] visited;
    ArrayList dp;
     int polaczenia=0;
     int bribe=0;
    Graph(int size){
        aL = new ArrayList<>();
        visited =new boolean[size];
        dp = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            aL.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }
    public void addEdge(int v, int w,int b){
        aL.get(v).add(new Para(w,b));
      //  System.out.println("dodaje zaleznosc "+(v)+" do o wadze "+w+" "+b);
    }

    public void modDijkstra(int cur,int stop){
        if(cur==stop){
            return;
        }

        PriorityQueue<Para> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(aL.size(),Comparator.comparingInt(o->o.left));
        int[] distance = new int[aL.size()];
        Arrays.fill(distance,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        pq.add(new Para(0,cur));
        distance[cur] = 0;
        while (!pq.isEmpty()){
            int node =pq.poll().getRight();
            for(Para p:aL.get(node)){
                if(distance[p.left]>distance[node]+p.getRight()){
                    distance[p.left]=distance[node]+p.getRight();
                    if(p.right!=0){
                        bribe+=p.getRight();
                        p.setRight(p.getRight()+1);

                    }
                    pq.add(new Para(distance[p.left],p.left));
                }
            }


        }

 
    }



}
class Para{
    int left;
    int right;
    Para(int l, int r){
        this.left = l;
        this.right= r;
    }

}



I would recommend describing the problem (more concisely) in your own words (or at least quote the entire problem, as it seems that some context has been omitted, perhaps accidentally).

@Unmitigated u can check it here:
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/575/B

I've edited in a summary of the problem into the question. You may roll back the edit if you find it unhelpful.

All that matters is how many bribes you have to pay.  So you need only concern yourself with locations that can ONLY be reached by going the wrong way along an edge.

@ravenspoint  so i can stay with my Dijkstra or implement BFS?
Maybe i dont understand but still i dont see that yours solution improve my running time becuse we have to still iterator through adjacencylist to find this specific connection

You do not need to calculate the paths, only the number of bribes required.  That is, count the number of stops that can only be reached by bribing.

Does my answer work for you or is something missing?

It is always optimal to take the shortest path between consecutive locations, but Dijkstra's algorithm is not needed. Notice that the graph is a tree, meaning that the shortest path between two nodes is always the combination of the path from one of the nodes to the lowest common ancestor and the path from the LCA to the other node. We may root the tree arbitrarily without affecting the answer.
For this problem, we need to count the number of times the driver moves up from each node and moves down into each node. These updates for each path can be done in constant time with difference arrays over the tree. After handling all the stops, we can push all the changes in the difference array from child nodes to parent nodes to accumulate the actual traversal count in each direction.
Then, we can find for each one-way road the number of times it was passed through in the wrong direction. The cost of bribes will be 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^(count - 1) (due to doubling the price each time). This is clearly a geometric sequence, the sum of which is 2^count - 1. We can obtain the value of this expression with binary exponentiation or by precomputing all the powers of 2 (modulo 10^9 + 7) from 0 to K (the number of stops).
Sample implementation:
private static final int MOD = 1000000007;
private static List<Integer>[] adj;
private static int[] depth, pathup, pathdown;
private static int maxLog;
private static int[][] ancestor;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    record Road(int from, int to) {}
    var oneWay = new ArrayList<Road>();
    try (var br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        int towns = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        adj = new List[towns + 1];
        for (int i = 1; i <= towns; i++)
            adj[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        depth = new int[towns + 1];
        pathup = new int[towns + 1];
        pathdown = new int[towns + 1];
        maxLog = 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(towns - 1);
        ancestor = new int[towns + 1][maxLog + 1];
        for (int i = 1; i < towns; i++) {
            var st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            int a = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),
                    dir = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            adj[a].add(b);
            adj[b].add(a);
            if (dir == 1) oneWay.add(new Road(a, b));
        }
        DFS(1, 0);
        int stops = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()), prevLoc = 1;
        var st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < stops; i++) {
            int stop = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), lca = LCA(prevLoc, stop);
            ++pathup[prevLoc];
            ++pathdown[stop];
            --pathup[lca];
            --pathdown[lca];
            prevLoc = stop;
        }
        pushUp(1);
        long bribe = 0;
        for (var road : oneWay) {
            int wrongWayUses = depth[road.from] < depth[road.to] ? pathup[road.to] : pathdown[road.from];
            long total = 1, square = 2;
            while (wrongWayUses > 0) {
                if ((wrongWayUses & 1) == 1) total = total * square % MOD;
                square = square * square % MOD;
                wrongWayUses >>= 1;
            }
            bribe = (bribe + total - 1) % MOD;
        }
        System.out.println(bribe);
    }
}
private static void DFS(int curr, int par) {
    ancestor[curr][0] = par;
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxLog; i++) 
        ancestor[curr][i] = ancestor[ancestor[curr][i - 1]][i - 1];
    depth[curr] = depth[par] + 1;
    for (int next : adj[curr])
        if (next != par)
            DFS(next, curr);
}
private static int LCA(int x, int y) {
    if (depth[x] < depth[y]) return LCA(y, x);
    for (int i = maxLog; i >= 0; i--)
        if (depth[x] - (1 << i) >= depth[y]) x = ancestor[x][i];
    if (x == y) return x;
    for (int i = maxLog; i >= 0; i--)
        if (ancestor[x][i] != ancestor[y][i]) {
            x = ancestor[x][i];
            y = ancestor[y][i];
        }
    return ancestor[y][0];
}
private static void pushUp(int curr) {
    for (int next : adj[curr])
        if (next != ancestor[curr][0]) {
            pushUp(next);
            pathup[curr] += pathup[next];
            pathdown[curr] += pathdown[next];
        }
}

Total time complexity: O(N log N + K log N + N log K).

If there are N towns and N-1 roads and the graph is connected then the graph must be a tree.
To find the path from one town to another town you need to backtrack up the tree to the lowest common ancestor and then descend the tree to the destination. This can be achieved efficiently by:

Performing a breadth-first search over the tree and giving each town a unique bfs_index based on the order they are reached by the breadth-first search.
When you want to find the lowest common-ancestor then if the bfs_index for the towns are not equal then repeatedly backtrack from the town with the highest bfs_index until they are equal.

You can do that like this:
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main {
    static final String[] examples = new String[]{
        "2\n1 2 0\n1\n2",
        "2\n1 2 1\n1\n2",
        "2\n2 1 1\n1\n2",
        "4\n2 1 1\n2 3 1\n1 4 1\n2\n3 4",
        "4\n2 1 1\n2 3 1\n1 4 1\n8\n3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4"
    };
    static final int [] expectedCosts = new int[]{
        0,
        0,
        1,
        2,
        37
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Parser.parse(System.in);
        int cost;
        for (int i = 0; i < Main.examples.length; ++i)
        {
            cost = Graph.parse(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    Main.examples[i].getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                )
            );
            System.out.println(i + ": " + cost + " - " + Main.expectedCosts[i]);
        }
        
    }
}

class Graph {
    class Town {
        static final int UNVISITED = 0;
        int bfs_index = UNVISITED;
        final ArrayList<Road> roads = new ArrayList<Road>();
        Road parent = null;
    }

    class Road{
        static final boolean ASCENDING = true;
        static final boolean DESCENDING = !ASCENDING;

        final Town from;
        final Town to;
        final boolean bidirectional;
        boolean isAscending = false;
        int cost = 0;
        
        Road(
            final int from,
            final int to,
            final boolean bidirectional
        )
        {
            this.from = Graph.this.towns[from];
            this.to = Graph.this.towns[to];
            this.bidirectional = bidirectional;
            this.from.roads.add(this);
            this.to.roads.add(this);
        }
        
        Town other(final Town town)
        {
            if (town == this.from)
            {
                return this.to;
            }
            else if (town == this.to)
            {
                return this.from;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        
        void travel(final boolean ascending)
        {
            if (!this.bidirectional && ascending != this.isAscending)
            {
                ++this.cost;
            };
        }
        
        BigInteger totalCost()
        {
            return BigInteger.ONE
                     .shiftLeft(this.cost)
                     .subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    }
    
    final int size;
    final Town[] towns;
    
    Graph(int size)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.towns = new Town[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            this.towns[i] = new Town();
        }
    }
    
    void bfs()
    {
        final LinkedList<Town> visitQueue = new LinkedList<Town>();
        int bfs_index = 0;
        Town town = this.towns[0];
        Town destination;
        while (town != null)
        {
            town.bfs_index = ++bfs_index;
            for (Road road: town.roads)
            {
                destination = road.other(town);
                if (destination.bfs_index == Town.UNVISITED)
                {
                    road.isAscending = road.from == town;
                    destination.parent = road;
                    visitQueue.addLast(destination);
                }
            }
            town = visitQueue.pollFirst();
        }
    }
    
    void travel(final Town from, final Town to)
    {
        Town f = from;
        Town t = to;

        while (f != t)
        {
            if (f.bfs_index > t.bfs_index)
            {
                f.parent.travel(Road.DESCENDING);
                f = f.parent.other(f);
            }
            else
            {
                t.parent.travel(Road.ASCENDING);
                t = t.parent.other(t);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int parse(final InputStream input) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
        int towns = scanner.nextInt();
        Graph g = new Graph(towns);
        for (int i = 0; i < towns-1; i++) {
            scanner.nextLine();
            int f = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
            int t = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
            boolean bidirectional = scanner.nextInt() == 0;
            g.new Road(f, t, bidirectional);
        }

        g.bfs();

        scanner.nextLine();
        int num_stops = scanner.nextInt();
        Town current_stop = g.towns[0];
        Town next_stop;
        scanner.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < num_stops; i++) {
            next_stop = g.towns[scanner.nextInt() - 1];
            g.travel(current_stop, next_stop);
            current_stop = next_stop;
        }
        scanner.close();
        
        BigInteger cost = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 1; i < towns; ++i)
        {
            cost = cost.add(g.towns[i].parent.totalCost());
        }
        return cost
                 .mod(new BigInteger("1000000007"))
                 .intValue();
    }
}


Going through every node in the path in travel makes the time complexity for handling all stops O(NK), which is much too slow to pass.
